# Any good resource to learn CIL?

Tags: .net, cil, il

I am trying to learn the CIL , i.e Common Intermediate Language. Also known as IL, MSIL etc.

(Please don't comment asking me why exactly I am doing this or what I will gain from this)

My problem is that I've found *very* few resources on the internet and most of them are just brief blog posts. Any help?

Comment: Learning MSIL is very useful if you ever want to use Reflection Emit or write a compiler.  It's also very useful to help figure out what the C# compiler is doing behind the scenes in corner cases.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm

Comment: I just use reflector - compile something similar in c# and see what was emited

Comment: Jason Bock's book is good - though it is pre generics: http://www.amazon.com/CIL-Programming-Under-Hood-NET/dp/1590590414/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1325889127&sr=8-3

Comment: This question is very ON topic, so please reopen it.

Comment: Another great way to view either lowered C#, IL, or assembly is [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good [IL introductory article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301368.aspx) by John Robbins on MSDN magazine. And here's [another article](http://csharpcomputing.com/Tutorials/Lesson8.htm) for getting started. For more details you may checkout Partition III of [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).

Answer (score 8):

Internet resources--while certainly a good start--will only take you so far. I would highly recommend "Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler" by Serge Lidin, Apress 2006.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`OpCodes` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes) to see everything that MSIL can do, then use Reflector/ILSpy or ILDASM on simple functions to see how to do it  (Reflector/ILSpy have a better UI).
You can also use LINQPad to translate C# or VB directly to MSIL faster.

You will need a basic understanding of how stack-based languages work.